# AWS Athena rounds numbers when importing CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-athena

I'm trying to import some data from a CSV into AWS Athena that looks like this.

When I then view the data in a table **test_job_id** rounds the data to 1550000000000. Does anyone know how I can get the full values such as 1546910000000 for the **test_job_id** instead of having it round each time?

Here is the create table query that Athena is using:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS automation_test_results.automation_test_results (
  `test_job_id` decimal(13),
  `testrail_id` string,
)
```

**Update:** I am now viewing the file in TextEdit. Here is what the data looks like. When I upload this to athena I now get empty squares instead for every row in the `test_job_id` column. Here is the data:[image]

I do see the values correctly if I specify `string` for the type for test_job_id, but I would prefer it be some numerical value.

Comment: Instead of using `decimal`, you should try a column type of  `BIGINT`

Comment: @DerekPollard Tried that. If I do `BIGINT` it just leaves blanks for every row in that column.

Comment: Hmmm....do you have an example of the imported data? maybe just a few lines

Comment: Because `1.55E+12` would be `1550000000000`, so it might be an issue with the data being imported

Comment: What does the data in the CSV look like outside of Excel?  Like in a text editor.

Comment: The data inside the csv is what's in the screen shot. I clicked into the first row to show the actual number.

Comment: Excel can do things you don't want.  Show it in a text editor.

Comment: Yeah, I would hazard to guess that the data is being modified by an application (probably the one you use to view it with). I suggest opening the file with vim or something

Comment: Ah, I am viewing the csv file with excel, so that may be it. I'll expand the screen shot to make it clearer.

Comment: No, please open the CSV file in a text editor (not Excel).

Answer (score 2):

With some experimentation I was able to import your data *if* I removed the quotes from the decimal number.  My table create looks like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS athena_test.s3data (
  `test_job_id` decimal,
  `testrail_id` string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://the-bucket/athena/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

and the data looks like:

```
1547559017125, "@C665"
1547559017126, "@C666"
1547559017127, "@C667"
```

If I tried to use `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde` as the row format it doesn't appear to like it either way though I'm much less familiar with doing it that way.

Is there anyway to generate your CSV with no quotes around the decimal number?